# Spring JDBC Template with business level transaction management

Tags: transactions, spring-jdbc, jdbctemplate, transactionmanager

I want to handle and rollback exceptions inside business service level, but when i use datasourcetransacitonmanager inside jdbctemplete it is just handle, database exceptions, do you have any suggestions? multiple management or ? merge the transaction managers?

Answer (score 0):

Check out @Transactional annotation on the service method. That should make anything within the service transactional to where if one fails it all rolls back.

http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/2.5.x/api/org/springframework/transaction/annotation/Transactional.html

Comment: I know the annotation, the problem is i do not want wait until database send me error, even i got runtimeexception i need to rollback some database operations done until that exception.